# How do I move an icon from the desktop to the menu in Gnome Flashback?

Tags: icons, gnome-panel

I have an icon for Photoshop that was added to my desktop by Play On Linux. I'd rather have that icon be in the Graphics submenu of my Main Menu.

How do I move it?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If not, is like to know! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, it is just slightly tricky. I will be using an application called Prototyper Free that I happen to have installed with WINE and on my desktop.

First we need to find out what the icon name/paths are for every desktop icon we want to move to the menu. I don't know where the relevant .desktop files are for PlayOnLinux apps, but WINE's are stored in `~/.local/share/applications/wine/programs/programName/program.desktop`.  Find the desktop files for your apps. Mine is located at:

```
~/.local/share/applications/wine/programs/Justinmind/Prototyper Free 5.6.1/Prototyper Free 5.6.1.desktop
```

Open the file and find the `Icon` and `Exec` fields; save the text in a blank text file for now.

[image]

Now open *Applications -> Accessories -> Main Menu*. Select the category/menu you want your icons to appear in and click *New Item* (if you want your apps to appear in the root menu, directly under "Applications" select "Applications" at the top).

[image]

Fill out the name and comment fields with whatever you want and put the text you got from the `Exec` line in the .desktop file earlier in the command field.

[image]

Click OK.

Now you have your menu item:

[image]

That icon doesn’t look so great though, does it? Head over to:

```
~/.local/share/applications
```

and find a file named `alacarte-made.desktop`. Open it up and replace the text in the `Icon=` section with the text you got at the beginning of the answer. Save the file. Now your menu entry's icon should look normal.

[image]

Alacarte (aka. Main Menu) will name each subsequent .desktop file `alacarte-made-1.desktop`, `alacarte-made-2.desktop`, etc. You will have to keep track of them when editing. Do not try to rename them, as it doesn't work and your menu items will disappear. I don't know why.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response. Unfortunately, I can't seem to locate the `program.desktop` file that's required to make this all work.

Comment: @DaveMG When I get time I will install PlayOnLinux and see if I can figure it out. In the meantime, see if `locate programname.desktop` returns anything useful (remember to replace `programname`with the name of your program!)